# Transaction management in iBATIS 3 inside an EJB (3.1) container

Tags: transactions, ejb-3.0, ibatis

Is anybody out there using iBATIS 3 as their persistence framework inside an EJB container? I recently started building a new system for which I choose EJB 3.1 (the version of EJB is actually irrelevant to this question) as my app framework and iBATIS 3 (this version is relevant!) as my persistence framework. My business logic is implemented in EJB 3.1 session beans that use iBATIS 3 for data access. I am running on GlassFish v3)

My issue with this stack has been transaction management. I have solved my problem by writing some simple integration code, but I was little surprised I had to do this. So I decided to post this to see if others have run into this and if so how they solved the problem.

My requirement is for iBATIS 3 to transparently use the EJB transaction (typically defined declaratively) in the session bean method. iBATIS 3 provides 2 transaction factories JdbcTransactionFactory and ManagedTransactionFactory and I found that neither one works correctly in an EJB environment (and looking at the iBATIS source it is clear why it fails).

The JdbcTransactionFactory is inappropriate since I want any calls to sqlSession.commit() or sqlSession.rollback() to be ignored. So I thought ok I should use the ManagedTransactionFactory since it does cause any calls to sqlSession.commit() or sqlSession.rollback() to be ignored, however it also causes sqlSession.close() to *not* close the connection that iBATIS opened from the DataSource in sqlSession.open() (the DataSource is a container managed DataSource object I provide to iBATIS). This causes the GlassFish to exhaust its connect pool and the application fails.

So I wrote a new TransactionFactory implementation, EJBTransactionFactory, that causes sqlSession.commit() or sqlSession.rollback() to do nothing, but **does close** the connection when sqlSession.close() is called.

I suspect other people have run into this, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up getting discussed/resolved here: http://www.mail-archive.com/user-java@ibatis.apache.org/msg16138.html